# How to take out the noises of the servo motor?

Tags: raspbian, gpio, pigpio, servo, pi-gpio

I am using the 3b+ raspberry, while the accelerometer is acquiring data the servo is creating some noises which may give false readings. Does anyone have any idea how to get rid of these noises?
I am using the GPIO library, if anyone has any suggestions for the library as well, please advise me.

Thank you
Best Regards

Comment: what do you mean by `noises`?

Comment: It shakes. For instance, if it is at a certain angle, it has a weird movement (I think they call it chattering/jittering).

Comment: Try a capacitor: https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/175431/52138

Comment: @goldilocks thank you, do you have any idea how to connect the capacitor to a rasp., honestly speaking I don't know how to do to so.

Comment: Which library are you using?  Where is the code?

Comment: @MohamadDabdoub It's exactly the same as with the arduino, in parallel on the 5V power connection.